# Store values in a table in my database and display the result in a datagrid

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, datagridview

The SQL query is supposed fetch product id from the products table and through the for loop I'm trying store the values in the product id column of the Inventory table.

Here is the code:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\MAYUR\Desktop\TechUp\Srinath\SrinathDB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30")
con.Open()
Dim dsInventory As New DataSet()
Dim adpInventory = New SqlDataAdapter("Select I.Inventory_Date, P.Product_ID, P.Product_Name, P.Product_Unit,I.Available_Stock From Products P, Inventory I where P.Product_ID = I.Product_ID", con)
adpInventory.Fill(dsInventory)
dgInventory.DataSource = dsInventory.Tables(0)

Dim dsProducts As New DataSet()
Dim adpProducts As New SqlDataAdapter("Select * from Products", con)
adpProducts.Fill(dsProducts)
For Each ProductRow As DataRow In dsProducts.Tables(0).Rows
    Dim idval As Integer = Integer.Parse(ProductRow("Product_ID").ToString())
    Dim sqlcomm As New SqlCommand("insert into Inventory(Product_ID) Values(@id)", con)
    sqlcomm.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = idval
    sqlcomm.ExecuteNonQuery()
Next
dgInventory.Refresh()
```

Comment: Can you explain better what is the problem in the above code? Do you get an error message? (if yes what is the message?), the results are not what you expected to be? (then explain what are the results and what do you expect them to be)

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: How do you find the correct P.Product_ID to place it into the I.Product_ID? I don't see any matching, so is it per order? Anyhow, it seems to be at this stage like something that can be easily achieved using a SQL statement only.

Comment: Firstly, you don't " store the values in the product id column of the Inventory table". You might be inserting rows in that table. You might be updating rows in that table. But we don't know exactly what you are trying to do. You select rows from the inventory table so it is not clear why you cannot do this in a single tsql statement. And it is highly unlikely that a new row in the inventory table is valid with only a single column populated. If that works. you likely have serious schema issues that will eventually need to be addressed.

Comment: You haven't asked an actual question, which we need in order to provide an answer. We assume you are having some kind of problem with the above code, but you haven't explained what the problem is. Is there an error? Exception message?

Comment: Why would you want to insert new Inventory records with only a ProductID? This could make quite a mess in you Inventory table.